# Spark program to monitor the executors performance

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, driver, executor, bigdata

I am working on a spark program that monitor each executors' performance such as mark down when one executor start to work and when it finishes its job. I am thinking two ways to do that:

First, develop programs so when the executor starts work, it mark down the current time to a file, when it finishes, mark down that time to the same file. In the ends, all "log" files will be spread the whole cluster networks except for the driver machine.

Second, since executors will report to driver periodically, each time the driver receives message from executors, if the message contains "start" and "finish" information, let the driver record everything.

Is that possible?

Comment: The Spark logging system already does this.

Comment: See this stuff here. Spark already have something like that: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to Monitor the executor performance as well as application performance

Best ways are to Monitor  with the help of Spark Web UI and Other Monitoring tools available Open Source (Ganglia)

You Need to Monitor your application whether your cluster is under utilized or not how much resources are used by your application which you have created.

Monitoring can be done using various tools eg. Ganglia From Ganglia you can find **CPU, Memory and Network Usage**.Based on Observation about CPU and Memory Usage you can get a **better idea what kind of tuning is needed for your application**

Hope this Helps!!!....